# gradle compile failed to find

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have already included some libraries in former versions of Android Studio with compile '...'.
Now I want to include the following:

https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart with `compile 'com.db.williamchart:williamchart:1.0.0'`

If I do that, Android Studio tells me:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.db.williamchart:williamchart:1.0.0
Open File - Open in Project Structure dialog
```

I have already added **mavenCentral()** in my Project build.gradle. The file looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I have now read that you can search your maven here http://search.maven.org/ and I can't find the library I want there, BUT it seems that noone else has the same problem like me.

I always have troubles with gradle so I would not be surprised if it's up to me.

Comment: [The instructions on the Web site](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) have you run the **`gradle install`** task on your local clone of the project repo to install the library into your local repository. Did you do that?

Comment: I typed (successfully) '**$ ./gradlew installDebug**' as well as '**$ ./gradlew install**' into the gradle console  ... I am sorry if i misunderstand you because i am a real noob in gradle

Comment: Can anyone try it out in his own project? I still can't find a solution...